# How to encode borderAgentID string into Data properly for THClient “storeCredentials”

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Im currently trying to store my Thread Network credentials using ThreadNetwork framework in iOS.

To use the “storeCredentials” method I need to pass 2 Data objects, one for borderAgentID and another one for the network dataset, but no matter how I convert my strings into Data, I always receive back “Invalid parameters provided…”